# Showing a set is an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to work through Hartshorne's book and while working through one of the exercises, I need to show the following:

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $Y \subseteq A^3$ be the set $Y=\{(t,t^2,t^3)\;|\;t \in k\}$. Show that $Y$ is an affine variety.

The rest of the problem I have completed. I'm just not sure how to show that this set is closed and irreducible. I assume that they intend for $A^3$ to have the Zariski topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** First show that $Y$ is the zero set of the ideal $I = (z - x^3, y - x^2)$.  Then show that $I$ is a prime ideal by showing that the quotient $k[x, y, z]/I$ is isomorphic to $k[x]$ (and hence an integral domain).

Comment: I have actually already shown all these things. The problem also asks to show that $Y$ has dimension $1$ but I did this by showing $A(Y)=A/I(Y) \cong k[x]$. But to use that, I had to show that $I$ was an affine variety. I see that I missed $I$ is prime so that it is irreducible. But how does this show that $Y$ is closed?

Comment: When you showed that $Y$ is the zero set of $I$, this shows that $Y$ is closed (by definition!) in the Zariski topology.

Comment: Of course! I felt it was something obvious and indeed it was. I'm still getting the feel of the Zariski topology. Thank you for pointing it out!